# Efficient way to store big data in Python (genome wide analysis)

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am currently trying to proceed a genome wide analysis, and I really wonder if I am using the right structure format. I could not find real information on the web about how and where to store your data to be more efficient.

In that case, the data is organized this way :

one file (.ped)  = one chromosome

one chromosome = 3000 lines

one line = one individual with its identification followed by its genotype (more than 100 000 characters).

The whole file is more than 1,2 Go. I use pickle to load it.

I tried different ways of storing the data, for example it takes only 30 seconds to store data from 4 files if I put it all in a list this way :

```
pedFile = [
[['G01231GHS', 'G01231GHS', 0, 0, 1, 1], 'ATTTCTC', 'TGTCT00CTGA'],
[['G01324GHS', 'G01324GHS', 0, 0, 1, 1], 'ATT0TAG', 'TGCT000ATGA']
]
```

where the first string is first chromosome analyzed, etc.

```
index_chr = {'chr2':1, 'chr5':2, 'chr13':3, 'chr16':4}
```

I also tried this type of structure :

```
pedDico = {
'G01231GHS': {'id':['G01231GHS', 'G01231GHS', 0, 0, 1, 1], 'chr2': 'ATT0CTC', 'chr5': 'TGTCT00CTGA'},
'G01324GHS': {'id':['G01324GHS', 'G01324GHS', 0, 0, 1, 1], 'chr2':'ATT0TAG', 'chr5': 'TGCT000ATGA'}
}
```

But none of the structure above seems to be more efficient.

The matter comes with the need to filter the data, which means using for loops to compare the data between the individuals, which means that it takes hours to run. I also tried a numpy array, but it takes too much time to build.

Could you think of a smarter structure ? Am I getting it all wrong trying to use lists, dictionaries or numpy array to deal with such big datas ?

Comment: I suggest looking at hdf5 for this sort of data. It compresses very well and retrieval time is fast. Take a look at PyTables or h5py (C to Python mapping)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `shelve`.  It will pickle your dictionary, but only unpickle it one entry at a time.

```
import shelve
db=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True)
db.update(pedDico)
db.close()
```

Then when you want to use it later

```
import shelve
db=shelve.open(filename)
for dbKey in list(db.keys()):
    data=db[dbKey]  #only unpickle this dictionary entry
    #Do stuff with data
    db.sync() #clear db[dbkey] out of memory and move on
```

This way you don't have to keep loading the big database in and out of memory all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Genome sequencing is as computation heavy task, as is described there are huge amount of data. Maybe python is not the right tool to do it.
Take a look at some GPU accelerated way of it such as BarraCUDA (http://seqbarracuda.sourceforge.net/index.html)